# How to set environment variables in a cross-platform way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

For Windows, my Node scripts should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start-docs": "SET NODE_ENV=development&&babel-node ./docs/Server.js"
}
```

But on Linux there's no `SET`, so it would be like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start-docs": "NODE_ENV=development&&babel-node ./docs/Server.js"
}
```

Is there a way to declare environment variables in a way that is consistent and cross-platform?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I recently came across the [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) project. It's pretty straight-forward

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

That will set the `build` environment variable to `production` regardless of the OS.

Comment: cross-env turns to maintenance mode and the repo has been archived

Comment: @CallMeLaNN Yes, but not because it's deprecated, but because it's author deems it feature-complete. He is committed to keep providing bugfixes and keep supporting new Node JS versions. So imho, cross-env is still the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would vote against setting this in package.json because *environment variables* should be set dependent on your environment while package.json is most likely the same for every environment (you commit it to your version control system, right?). Instead you should use something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) if you are looking for a clean and generic solution.

Comment: dotenv recommends against committing the .env file. This is a good idea as you don't want to git-wrestle over your specific local changes with your team mates. However it is also quite helpful to have some default configuration committed to the code base so it can get up and running ASAP. The NPM library dotenv-extended seems to handle this case, where you commit in a default set of environment variables, while still excluding the users local .env file. It doesn't handle cases where you may want multiple defaults (ie. point to dev vs point fully to local) but is better than .env alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna use any third-party tools there is an easy way to achieve this using a `nodejs` script.

Step-by-step guide:

1. Create `./scripts/set-env.js` file with the following content:

```js
import { argv, env } from "node:process"
import { spawn } from "node:child_process"

// Set your custom env variables here
const extenv = {
    NODE_ENV: "development",
}

spawn(argv[2], argv.slice(3), {
    env: { ...env, ...extenv },
    stdio: "inherit",
})
```

Notes:

- `argv[2]` is a passed-in command to run in a child shell
- `argv.slice(3)` - passed-in arguments
- `...env` - used to preserve current shell environment variables
- `stdio: "inherit"` - used to pipe the child shell output into the current shell

2. Edit your `package.json`'s scripts section:

```json
"scripts": {
    "set-env": "node ./scripts/set-env.js",
    "start-docs": "npm run set-env -- babel-node ./docs/Server.js"
}
```

Notes: `--` is used to pass command and arguments to the `set-env` script.

### Advantages

- Cross-platform
- No third-party dependencies
- Fully customisable