# Using environment variables in npm scripts across platforms

Tags: npm, environment-variables, cross-platform

I am building a package.json and use "npm run" to run some scripts, to be exactly, https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts.

My script would need to expand some environment variables and I want to make it cross platform compatible. For example, my script would say

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "md %npm_package_version%\helloworld"
}
```

But it's currently running on Windows because the expansion of environment variables. Linux would use `md $npm_package_version\helloworld`.

Does `npm` comes with a mechanism to convert environment variables expansion so that it works across platforms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set environment variables in a cross-platform way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446734/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-a-cross-platform-way)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To make it cross-platform, use [`cross-var`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var):

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "cross-var md %npm_package_version%\helloworld"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`npm` doesn't appear to have a cross platform way to expand environment variables, but you do have node at your disposal, so I'd recommend implementing all your scripts as node scripts, then you can access `process.env` and cross-platform filesystem functions, like `mkdirSync`.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "node utils/mdkir.js"
}
```

**utils/mkdir.js**

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

fs.mkdirSync(process.env.npm_package_version + '/helloworld');
```

Comment: "npm doesn't appear to have a cross platform way to expand environment variables" – I came to the same conclusion. Do you happen to have a quote from the official docs?

Comment: Closest I got was this: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shell which explains the default shell on Windows is `cmd`.