# How to get environment variable in npm script?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am trying to access an enviroment variable in the npm script itself like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha --root ../SERVER/routes -- --recursive"
},
```

And start this script like so:

```
SERVER=somewhere npm test
```

How can I get the resolved value of `SERVER` variable in the npm script in the package.json itself?

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: @havenchyk Because I'm trying to automate this test in TeamCity, and so I pass the `SERVER` as an enviroment variable from there

Comment: package.json is just a json file, you can't get it there afaik, but you can get this variable in your script with `process.env`

Comment: @havenchyk Works! That was quick. Thanks :) I can't mark the answer right now, until then, **Bonus question:** are there any conditions for setting an environment variable name? Like can I set `my-server` as env variable?

Comment: I posted it as an answer as well :) as for bonus question, sorry, I didn't get it :)

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331625/using-environment-variables-in-npm-scripts-across-platforms/34260565

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will using `$SERVER` work for you?

`"scripts": {
  "test": "istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha --root ../$SERVER/routes -- --recursive"
}`

Comment: That does not work cross-platform (i.e. on Windooze).

Answer (score 14):

For the windows users, you may use your variables like this: `%SERVER%` instead of `$SERVER`.

Or better approach to use [`cross-env` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) which will allow you to do it like linux on all platforms:

```sh
npm i cross-env
```

And use it :

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "cross-env-shell \"istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha --root ../$SERVER/routes -- --recursive\""
}
```

Comment: Glad that the accepted answer worked for the OP, but this should really be the accepted answer instead