# How to create build configurations in a TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, build, configuration, configuration-files

I have a **typescript node.js** project where there are some **parameters in code** and in json configuration **files** that depend on whether I want to build a development or a release version.

Up to now, I always change them by hand which is annoying when you forget something and upload it to a web platform that runs the app just to notice you have to do it again.

How could I proceed so that I just have to pass a parameter when transpiling and I get the right values in code and the right json configs (like foo_dev.json and foo_release.json)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need environment depending configuration.
Here is a example how it is done in angular cli project: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Similar for the nodejs project: https://medium.com/@jinmatt/config-management-for-node-js-based-on-runtime-environment-variables-55b3c6d82f5c

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables.

Environment variables are accessible in nodejs/typescript under the `env` property or `process` (`process.env`).

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
//Print out all env vars
console.log(process.env)
// { MYCONFIGFILE: "foo_dev.json" }
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env.MYCONFIGFILE,'utf8'));
```

Different operating systems have different ways of setting them.
You can use `cross-env` to resolve the differences.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446734/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-a-cross-platform-way/32446795) is a cross-platform solution.