# How to set or change user variable in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I want to set/change user variable in my windows/Linux system. one of them is my `APP_SOME_VAR` variable.

When I run `env` in the command line I'm getting a list of my user variables.

When I run this code in my `file.js` it doesn't change my variable in the command line.

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

let output = execSync(`echo blabla && set APP_SOME_VAR=blabla`);
```

After I run the file, I do this in the command line:

```
node app.js
env | grep SOME
```

But I get nothing from: `APP_SOME_VAR`

How to do that with nodejs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set environment variables in a cross-platform way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446734/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-a-cross-platform-way)

Comment: no, because I don't want to change the variable from package.json, only from my `file.js` file

Comment: Usually, you can set environmental vars only temporarily, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519452/is-it-possible-to-permanently-set-environment-variables has a workaround.